# PHP redirect to AJAX undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to do a redirect with PHP via AJAX but always appears as undefined url. I'm trying to make PHP check the user if true it passes but if false it does the redirect. Can anyone help me please?

Button:

```
<div class="checkout-button"><a id="button-quotation" class="button">Click Me</a></div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button-quotation').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/quotation',
      success: function(data){
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
      }
    })
});});
```

PHP:

```
public function quotation(){
    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', 'SSL');

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just do `echo $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')` in ur PHP file?

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework?

Comment: Roy M J same error. Davide Pastore OpenCart.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using frame works in frameworks $this->redirect is used for redirection (i.e header("location:xx.php").But here u need to print it then only ajax will get the url...use echo insted of redirect

```
echo $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL');
```

and in ajax get rquest also just use data not data.redirect.if you use any json format then only it would be used

```
success: function(data){
    window.location.href = data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button-quotation').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/quotation',
      success: function(data){
        window.location.href = data;
      }
    })
});});

public function quotation(){
    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', 'SSL');

        echo $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL');
    }
}
```